# No such property: COMPILE_ONLY_CONFIGURATION_NAME for class: org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin

Tags: grails, gradle, gradlew

I have Groovy and Grails project, and I have used the asset-pipeline.

Grails: 3.0.17 # Gradle: 2.12

In my `build.gradle` file I have applied asset-pipeline as below :

```
apply plugin: "asset-pipeline"
```

While building the project i am getting following error :

> org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':ciab-base'.
>       at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:154)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:59)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:492)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:86)
>       at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
>       at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56)
>   Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'asset-pipeline']
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:147)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:102)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:113)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:80)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:136)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:46)
>       at org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginAware$apply.call(Unknown Source)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
>       at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
>       at build_eutmpfkdca3gfie59pyomub8f.run(/home/urvin/Urvin/Repo/ciab-plugin/ciab-base/build.gradle:32)
>       at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
>       ... 35 more
>   Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: COMPILE_ONLY_CONFIGURATION_NAME for class: org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin
>       at asset.pipeline.gradle.AssetPipelinePlugin$_createGradleConfiguration_closure2.doCall(AssetPipelinePlugin.groovy:191)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:67)
>       at org.gradle.internal.Actions$FilteredAction.execute(Actions.java:201)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:115)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.withType(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:126)
>       at org.gradle.api.DomainObjectCollection$withType$0.call(Unknown Source)
>       at asset.pipeline.gradle.AssetPipelinePlugin.createGradleConfiguration(AssetPipelinePlugin.groovy:189)
>       at asset.pipeline.gradle.AssetPipelinePlugin.apply(AssetPipelinePlugin.groovy:52)
>       at asset.pipeline.gradle.AssetPipelinePlugin.apply(AssetPipelinePlugin.groovy)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RulesCapablePluginApplicator.applyImperative(RulesCapablePluginApplicator.java:42)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:133)
>       ... 46 more

Comment: Are you sure you're using Gradle 2.12 or newer?

Comment: is there a chance you updated Gradle but still using an old gradle wrapper? check your wrapper.properites in `gradle` directory.

Comment: Yes gradle version is also 2.12 in the gradle-wrapper.properties, moreover when I use gradle -version it gives the version 2.12 only.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error.

This is due to a mismatch between the version of grails you're using, expecting gradle 2.11, and the asset pipeline plugin, which needs 2.12.

To solve it you can start grails with (replace by your path to gradle):

```
$ GRAILS_GRADLE_HOME=~/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/2.12/ grails
```

Comment: If it works. Set `export GRAILS_GRADLE_HOME=~/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/2.12/ ` to your `.bashrc`.